# How to send logs from a heroku app to grafana cloud?

Tags: javascript, python, grafana, grafana-loki

Grafana-Loki is a nice logging service and I want to deploy it for an app on Heroku. I've looked around and there doesn't seem to be too much information about this. I found [this](https://twitter.com/mrchrisadams/status/1349373487585107968) twitter thread which references [this](https://github.com/sleleko/devops-kb/blob/master/python/push-to-loki.py) python repository, but I don't totally understand what's going on. I'm running a small javascript app on heroku, and I want the logs to go to grafana cloud. How do I apply this python code to my situation? I'm not that technical so I get lost easily when applying something to my own situation.

Answer (score 0):

create a python project with the [code](https://github.com/sleleko/devops-kb) and deploy it on Heroku

get the logs from your javascript project through heroku

procedure [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains)

as configured in the code from [here](https://github.com/sleleko/devops-kb)

it should push the logs to your grafana cloud